# LINQ Multiple LIKE based on List

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a list of keywords in an ArrayList and I wanted to be able to build a query to find records in a table based on this keywords.

Since the list of keywords is dynamic I cannot build a fixed query here.

I do something like this:

```
foreach (string kw in keywords)
{
  query = query.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(kw));
}
```

The "StartsWith" is required here because I need to search those records that actually start with the provided keyword.

In T-SQL it Would be something like this

```
Select * from Table where 
Name like 'keyword1%' 
or Name like 'keyword2%'
or Name like 'keyword3%'
or ...
```

But I need to be able to do this in LINQ...Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This oughtta do it:

```
var query = table.Where(p => keywords.Any(kw => p.Name.StartsWith(kw)));
```

Comment: I wonder if LINQ to SQL is actually that smart. I know EF3.5 would miserably fail with such a query. Still my +1.

Comment: Using this I get the ""Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator." exception...

Comment: @Bathan: Huh; I guess @Steven's right then - L2S isn't smart enough for this. Unfortunately, I can't really see an easy way to rewrite it using `Contains`...

Comment: The above sentence is wrong, but even if corrected, L2S doesn’t know what to do with it. As you’ve said, it’s not smart enough.

Comment: "I wonder if LINQ to SQL is actually that smart." No, it will respond with an exception: "local sequences cannot be used.... and so on"

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = table.Where(p => keywords.Any(kw => p.Name.StartsWith(keyword1) || p.Name.StartsWith(keyword2) || p.Name.StartsWith(keyword3) || p.Name.StartsWith(keyword4)));
```

Hope it can help you and have a nice day.